# How to parse the JSON output of a running command?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing, stream

**Summary**: I would like to parse the JSON output of `tshark` as it is outputted.

As of now I was parsing normal output, line by line, and each line had the complete information. It was therefore a matter of

```
p = subprocess.Popen("/usr/bin/tshark", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
     for line in p.stdout:
         event = decode_event(line)
```

`tshark` can also output pretty-printed JSON via the `-T json` switch (I just give the first packet, the output is a list):

```
[
  {
    "_index": "packets-2018-03-08",
    "_type": "pcap_file",
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
      "layers": {
        "frame": {
          "frame.interface_id": "0",
          "frame.encap_type": "1",
          "frame.time": "Mar  8, 2018 16:17:20.478658037 CET",
          "frame.offset_shift": "0.000000000",
          "frame.time_epoch": "1520522240.478658037",
          "frame.time_delta": "0.000113952",
          "frame.time_delta_displayed": "0.000113952",
          "frame.time_relative": "3.351515496",
          "frame.number": "11133",
          "frame.len": "60",
          "frame.cap_len": "60",
          "frame.marked": "0",
          "frame.ignored": "0",
          "frame.protocols": "eth:ethertype:ip:tcp"
        },
        "eth": {
          "eth.dst": "00:50:56:bb:40:70",
          "eth.dst_tree": {
            "eth.dst_resolved": "Vmware_bb:40:70",
            "eth.addr": "00:50:56:bb:40:70",
            "eth.addr_resolved": "Vmware_bb:40:70",
            "eth.lg": "0",
            "eth.ig": "0"
          },
          "eth.src": "64:a0:e7:42:af:41",
          "eth.src_tree": {
            "eth.src_resolved": "Cisco_42:af:41",
            "eth.addr": "64:a0:e7:42:af:41",
            "eth.addr_resolved": "Cisco_42:af:41",
            "eth.lg": "0",
            "eth.ig": "0"
          },
          "eth.type": "0x00000800",
          "eth.padding": "00:00:00:00:00:00"
        },
        "ip": {
          "ip.version": "4",
          "ip.hdr_len": "20",
          "ip.dsfield": "0x00000000",
          "ip.dsfield_tree": {
            "ip.dsfield.dscp": "0",
            "ip.dsfield.ecn": "0"
          },
          "ip.len": "40",
          "ip.id": "0x00005a57",
          "ip.flags": "0x00000002",
          "ip.flags_tree": {
            "ip.flags.rb": "0",
            "ip.flags.df": "1",
            "ip.flags.mf": "0"
          },
          "ip.frag_offset": "0",
          "ip.ttl": "125",
          "ip.proto": "6",
          "ip.checksum": "0x0000dd25",
          "ip.checksum.status": "2",
          "ip.src": "10.237.78.2",
          "ip.addr": "10.237.78.2",
          "ip.src_host": "10.237.78.2",
          "ip.host": "10.237.78.2",
          "ip.dst": "10.81.99.19",
          "ip.addr": "10.81.99.19",
          "ip.dst_host": "10.81.99.19",
          "ip.host": "10.81.99.19",
          "Source GeoIP: Unknown": "",
          "Destination GeoIP: Unknown": ""
        },
        "tcp": {
          "tcp.srcport": "31316",
          "tcp.dstport": "22",
          "tcp.port": "31316",
          "tcp.port": "22",
          "tcp.stream": "0",
          "tcp.len": "0",
          "tcp.seq": "3025",
          "tcp.ack": "774293",
          "tcp.hdr_len": "20",
          "tcp.flags": "0x00000010",
          "tcp.flags_tree": {
            "tcp.flags.res": "0",
            "tcp.flags.ns": "0",
            "tcp.flags.cwr": "0",
            "tcp.flags.ecn": "0",
            "tcp.flags.urg": "0",
            "tcp.flags.ack": "1",
            "tcp.flags.push": "0",
            "tcp.flags.reset": "0",
            "tcp.flags.syn": "0",
            "tcp.flags.fin": "0",
            "tcp.flags.str": "\u00c2\u00b7\u00c2\u00b7\u00c2\u00b7\u00c2\u00b7\u00c2\u00b7\u00c2\u00b7\u00c2\u00b7A\u00c2\u00b7\u00c2\u00b7\u00c2\u00b7\u00c2\u00b7"
          },
          "tcp.window_size_value": "2047",
          "tcp.window_size": "2047",
          "tcp.window_size_scalefactor": "-1",
          "tcp.checksum": "0x000073f4",
          "tcp.checksum.status": "2",
          "tcp.urgent_pointer": "0",
          "tcp.analysis": {
            "tcp.analysis.acks_frame": "11126",
            "tcp.analysis.ack_rtt": "0.000426928"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  <next packet>
```

What would be the correct approach to parse such a stream?

When searching for stream parsing, I found a few libraries (notably [`NAYA`](https://github.com/danielyule/naya)), but they require a file like object.

**It would seem that [`StringIO()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/io.html?highlight=stringio#module-io) would be appropriate but I do not know how to connect it with `stdout`?**

---

Per @omu_negru request, specifically in case of NAYA, directly attaching `stdout` as in

```
import naya
import subprocess

def handle_message(event):
    print(event)

cmd = "/usr/bin/tshark -i eth0 -T json"
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, bufsize=0, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
messages = naya.stream_array(proc.stdout)
for message in messages:
    handle_message(message)
```

raises an exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/dev/readtshark.py", line 12, in <module>
    for message in messages:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/naya/json.py", line 544, in stream_array
    token_type, token = next(token_stream)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: wouldn't you actually want to connect it to stdout?

Comment: use `jq` way faster than Python, just pipe the output of this into that

Comment: @omu_negru: yes of course, corrected. Thanks.

Comment: in that case, stdout is a file like object, you should just be able to pass that to the api....

Comment: @eagle: there is a lot of things which are then happening with the decoded packet, this is just the beginning so it needs to be a Python script

Comment: @omu_negru I tried to pass `p.stdout` to the api but it raises an exception. It may very well be the lib fault (I also asked there). Since this is specific to the library I was looking here for a more general approach (if there is one)

Comment: can you post some code and the actual exception?

Comment: @omu_negru: I appended both to the question

Comment: that really seems to be an issue with the library itself..... maybe you should ask at this point if you really want to stream the json and not just parse it when it's finished outputting

Comment: @omu_negru: the output is continuous (streaming), it never stops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual working version

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# tshark.py
import json, sys, time

output = sys.stdin
acc = '{'

def skip(output):
    while True:
        l = output.readline()
        if l.strip() != '{':
            continue
        else:
            break


skip(output)
print("starting")
while True:
    l = output.readline()
    if l.strip() != '':
        acc += l.strip()
    try:
        o = json.loads(acc)
        print(o)
        skip(output)
        acc = '{'
    except:
        pass
```

Launched with `sudo tshark -i wlp3s0 -T json | ./tshark.py`

Comment: Thanks - your answer inspired me another solution (also posted as an answer)

Answer (score 0):

@omu_negru's answer gave me an idea and I ended up using the solution below.

This is basically a continuous attempt to decode a JSON and once it is decoded, it is an event I process further (here, only print)

```
import subprocess
import json


def handle_message(event):
    print(event)

cmd = "/usr/bin/tshark -n -T json not broadcast and not multicast"
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
# skip first lines, until the [ which starts JSON
for line in proc.stdout:
    if line.decode().startswith('['):
        break
    else:
        continue

buffer = ""
for line in proc.stdout:
    # remove empty and "connection" lines (a comma)
    if not line.decode().strip(', \n'):
        continue
    buffer += line.decode('utf-8')
    try:
        event = json.loads(buffer)
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
        pass
    else:
        print(event)
        buffer = ""
```